# MySQL query results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on coding a design for a project and have spent the past few days trying to get this to work but cannot wrap my head around how to do it.

I'm trying to get the first 4 results from a database, and print them to the header. For each result, the nav list number needs to increase by one. For example:

```
<li class="nav_list" id="nav_list1">RESULT 1
<li class="nav_list" id="nav_list2">RESULT 2
```

Heres what I have so far, but have no idea how I could get it to display correctly. Any help is appreciated!

```
$query = "SELECT id, title, description, groupid FROM category LIMIT 0, 4";
            $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
            or die('Error querying database');
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()){
                $catID = $row[0];
                $catTITLE = $row[1];

            }
            ?> 
            <ul id="nav_line1">
            <?php
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
                print('<li class="nav_list" id="nav_list'.$i.'"><a href="catIDhere">catTITLEhere</a>|</li>');
            }
```

Comment: You are overwriting your variables in your `while` loop, you would need to use an array to store the results.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless. And that title - original ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
   echo <<<EOL
<li id="nav_list{$i}"><a href="{$row[0]}"> etc...

EOL;
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
    $query = "SELECT id, title, description, groupid FROM category ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 4";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
    or die('Error querying database');

      echo '<ul id="nav_line1">';
      while ($row = $result->fetch_row()){
        $catID = $row[0];
        $catTITLE = $row[1];           
            print('<li class="nav_list" id="nav_list'.$catID.'"><a href="'.$catID.'">'.$catTITLE.'</a>|</li>');
      }

     echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try somethin like this:

```
query = "SELECT id, title, description, groupid FROM category LIMIT 0, 4";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
        or die('Error querying database');
        $i = 1
        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()){
            $catID = $row[0];
            $catTITLE = $row[1];
            ?><ul id="nav_line1"><?php
            print('<li class="nav_list" id="nav_list'.$i.'"><a href="'.$catID.'">'.$catTITLE.'</a>|</li>');
            $i++
    }
```